# animate a circle inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to animate a circle inside an `html5` canvas but I'm having trouble when updating this circle AKA erasing the old position and drawn the new position 
my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/efcnM/):

As you can see the `clear` function is not clearing the entire circle but it's making it's color lighter is there anyway to clear the old circle without clearing the whole canvas or clearing a small rectangle that contain the circle ?

```
        var clearCircle = function (c) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();
        };
```

Comment: You have to clear the entire canvas and update your circle's position afterwards.

Comment: I don't want to clear the entire canvas i just want to erase the circle

Comment: Why don't you want that? It is a good practice to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change your composite mode to `copy` and move it globally. This will erase everything but will limit you to one draw operation.

**[Modified fiddle using copy composite mode](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/efcnM/2/)**.

The more correct way is to use either:

- `clearRect(x, y, w, h)` or
- `fillRect(x, y, w, h)`

the latter in case you need a background color. You can also use `drawImage(img, x, y)` if you want to fill the background with an image.

All of these methods (except composite mode) allow you to only draw the region that is necessary to update:

- Store the current position of the circle
- On next update, clearRect/fillRect etc. that position and width and height of circle. Add a pixel or two to the size to catch anti-aliased pixels (x - 1, y - 1, w + 2, h + 2).
- Draw the new circle and repeat:

Adjust this function to adopt:

```
var clearCircle = function (c) {
    ctx.clearRect(c.x - c.r - 1, c.y - c.r - 1, c.r*2+2, c.r*2+2);
};
```

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/efcnM/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `updateCanvas` method:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efcnM/1/)

Comment: i don't want to clear the entire canvas i just want to erase the circle

Comment: Don't draw it. I know you are trying to remove the last position from the canvas but that is just insane. If you really need this you can try drawing the circle's last position in the canvas backgroundcolor.